# aws, loadbalancer, what does dualstack mean in dns?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare, amazon-route53

Load Balancer has dns name `example-web-3333333.ap-northeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com`

and when we assign them in route53, it has `dualstack` at the front, so that
`dualstack.example-web-3333333.ap-northeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com`

I'm trying to setup a cdn (cloudflare) for static files, so that when a user hits `static.example.com` (whose domain is maintained by cloudflare), the dns should be
`example-web-3333333.ap-northeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com`

Should I include `dualstack` in this scenario as well?

Answer (score 1):

A dual stack DNS name in AWS means that it will resolve via both IPv6 and IPv4.

If you use the dualstack domain as a value for a CNAME it should enable a client to connect to your domain using IPv6 as well as IPv4.

> In either case, the console prepends dualstack. to the DNS name. When a client, such as a web browser, requests the IP address for your domain name (example.com) or subdomain name ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)), the client can request an IPv4 address (an A record), an IPv6 address (a AAAA record), or both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses (in separate requests). The dualstack. designation allows Route 53 to respond with the appropriate IP address for your load balancer based on which IP address format the client requested.

For reference, for an Alias record you would need to use an A record for IPv4 and an AAAA record for IPv6.

This [AWS blog article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dual-stack-ipv6-architectures-for-aws-and-hybrid-networks) describes various dual stack architectures, including how to use dual stack endpoints with Elastic Load Balancer.